# How to convert date column from string to date using with tmap in talend

Tags: talend, tmap

I am having a date column in string format, but I want to change that string into date format using with tmap in Talend. Now could you please tell me which expression I need to use to change the format from string to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built Talend Java routines for this purpose in a tMap.

Here is an example:

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", row1.dateStr)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: TalendDate.Format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TalendDate.parsedate("MM/dd/yy",column)

Comment: This expression will convert from string in one format to string in another format. As I understood your question you wanted to convert from "string" to "date".

Comment: Hi, I want to do something similar I am having  timestamp as string I want to convert it into date timestamp but I am getting two exceptions 1- : String index out of range: 13 and 2 -  Unparseable date: "1631898440"

Comment: @CS. Perhaps you need to convert the numeric timestamp to a date object first (e.g `new Date(Long.parseLong("1631898440"))`) and then use something like `TalendDate.Format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TalendDate.parsedate("MM/dd/yy",column)`